# Did I partition my drives incorrectly?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to partition and install alongside Windows. I didn't have any free space to begin with, so I followed a guide on this site that told me how to do so. But I think I messed up.

1) I think I took my 500GB with Windows on it and reduced it to only 20GB.

2) it told me to create positions for root, home, boot, var, and tmp, but something seems kind of off.....

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't exist.

Comment: @Muzaffar fixed.

Comment: Partitions seem OK as long as you are able to boot and use both OS.

Comment: @Muzaffar is there a way to increase the size of my Windows partition?

Comment: @Muzaffar on booting up I don't get the option to use Ubuntu. It goes straight to Windows. Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: `but something seems kind of off` is mega-vague.  What seems kind of off?

Comment: Windows partition seems small. You have to maintain at least 30% free space in NTFS partitions for them to work well. An with most desktop installs you just need the default of / (root) and swap. Adding /home or data partition(s) is often suggested. But you may only need other system folders as partitions with server or server type installs.

Comment: Please read this posts carefully: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu and also read some boring, yet useful information about partitioning: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition

Answer (score 1):

First, let's talk about Windows. At the bottom of your screen shot it says it is going to install the boot loader onto /dev/sda which is an SSD of 128GB. The partition layout in your screen shot is for /dev/sdb though and it says the Windows 7 loader partition is the first one on this drive. I don't know what you have on the 128GB SSD drive but please be sure your Windows is completely intact and that you know which drive has your boot sector. The Ubuntu installer thinks it is the 128GB SSD. It is usually correct but you should double check since it will affect your ability to boot when you are done.

Now we can talk about Ubuntu. You don't have to create separate partitions for all those mount points. In fact, you can just create one for the root (named simply "/") and the rest of the mount points will be created as subdirectories. If you assign mount points to additional partitions then those partitions will be mounted there and files that go into those directories will be located in their assigned partition. If you don't know what you are doing then just use one partition mounted as root to keep it simple.